# Overloading Operator *= and Operator+ in Matrix Template Class

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

The method `template <class T> const Matrix<T> &Matrix<T>::operator*=(T rhs)` for program `matrix.cc` should be able to returns calling object with matrix scaled by rhs, and the parameter rhs will be the same type as the matrix.

The error output that I am receiving from the compiler is:

```
[hw7] make clean && make bin/test_matrix_mul_assign && ./bin/test_matrix_mul_assign
rm -f bin/*
g++   -std=c++11   -Wall       -I inc   -I src   -c   src/test_matrix_mul_assign.cc -o bin/test_matrix_mul_assign.o
g++     bin/test_matrix_mul_assign.o   -o bin/test_matrix_mul_assign
Testing Matrix::operator*=
  Expected Matrix[0][0]: 2.0, Actual: 1
  FAILED
```

Could someone let me know why I receive this "Failed" output when I know I pass the `// TEST MUL ASSIGMENT OP CORRECT RETURN` section.

Here is my matrix.cc:

```
#include <matrix.h>

template <class T>
const Matrix<T> &Matrix<T>::operator*=(T rhs) {
  unsigned int rows_ = 0;
  unsigned int cols_ = 0;
  T **m_ = nullptr;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i) {
    m_[i] = new T[cols_];
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols_; ++j) {
      m_[i][j] = m_[i][j] * rhs;
    }
  }
  return *this;
}

template <class T>
const Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T> &rhs) const {
  if (!(this->cols_ == rhs.cols_) && (this->rows_ == rhs.rows_)) {
    std::cout << "Cannont add matrices. Wrong dimensions\n";
    exit(0);
  }

  Matrix<T> lhs;
  lhs.rows_ = this->rows_;
  lhs.cols_ = this->cols_;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lhs.rows; ++i) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < lhs.cols_; ++j) {
      lhs[i] += rhs[i];
    }
  }
  return lhs;
}
```

Here is my matrix.h:

```
#include <cassert>
// using assert
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Matrix {
 public:
  friend class MatrixTester;

  /* Times Equals Op: 1 Point
   *   Returns calling object with matrix scaled by rhs.
   *   Parameter:
   *    - rhs will be the same type as the matrix
   */
  const Matrix<T> &operator*=(T rhs);

  /* Add Op: 1 Point
   *   Returns the sum of calling object's matrix and rhs's matrix as a new
   *   object.
   * Precondition(s):
   *   - lhs rows must equal rhs rows
   *   - lhs cols must equal rhs cols
   */
  const Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> &rhs) const;

 private:
  T **m_;
  unsigned int rows_;
  unsigned int cols_;
};

#include <matrix.cc>  //NOLINT
```

This is my test_matrix_mul_assign.cc tester:

```
#include <test_matrix.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  MatrixTester tester;

  cout << "Testing Matrix::operator*=" << endl;
  if (tester.Test_MulAssignOp()) {
    cout << "  PASSED" << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  cout << "  FAILED" << endl;
  return 1;
}

bool MatrixTester::Test_MulAssignOp() const {
  const int kRows = 3, kCols = 4;
  Matrix<double> test_m;
  test_m.m_ = new double *[kRows];
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < kRows; ++i) {
    test_m.m_[i] = new double[kCols];

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < kCols; ++j)
      test_m.m_[i][j] = (i + 1.0) * (j + 1.0);
  }
  test_m.rows_ = kRows;
  test_m.cols_ = kCols;

  // TEST MUL ASSIGMENT OP CORRECT RETURN
  const Matrix<double> *m_ptr = &(test_m *= 2.0);
  if (m_ptr != &test_m) {
    cout << "  Expected return address of assigment: " << &test_m
         << ", Actual: " << m_ptr << endl;
    return false;
  }
  // TEST MUL ASSIGMENT OP CALCULATION
  if (test_m.m_[0][0] != 2.0) {
    cout << "  Expected Matrix[0][0]: 2.0, Actual: " << test_m.m_[0][0] << endl;
    return false;
  }
  if (test_m.m_[1][3] != 16.0) {
    cout << "  Expected Matrix[1][3]: 16.0, Actual: " << test_m.m_[1][3]
         << endl;
    return false;
  }
  if (test_m.m_[2][2] != 18.0) {
    cout << "  Expected Matrix[2][2]: 18.0, Actual: " << test_m.m_[2][2]
         << endl;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following variable definitions in the `operator*=` implementation:

```
unsigned int rows_ = 0;
unsigned int cols_ = 0;
T **m_ = nullptr;
```

They will shadow all of the members of the class. When you use `rows_`, `cols_` and `m_` later in the function definition they will refer to these local variables, not the class members of the current instance.

Therefore effectively your implementation of `operator*=` does nothing at all. It is not surprising that the test for the correct value then fails.

Simply remove these declarations, so that the names will refer to the current instance's members instead.

Then there is also not going to be any point to `m_[i] = new T[cols_];`. So remove that as well.

---

Why are there all of these dynamic allocations with `new` in the first place? This is seriously bad style and is going to cause you all kinds of issues. Use `std::vector` instead.

---

`class Matrix` also seems to be lacking a proper constructor. This again will cause all kinds of issues, especially when it leaves memory allocation to a user of the class.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the constructors because I was only worried about these two functions. There's another tester file that checks for the constructor, copy constructor, and destructor which my code passes for. I'll update my code.

Comment: @Kevondsmith Its fine. I am only mentioning it because the tests are using the class as if it didn't have a proper constructor in e.g. `Matrix<double> test_m;
  test_m.m_ = new double *[kRows];`. Either this line is wrong or the class is not designed as such a class should be designed.

Comment: Also another comment. You mentioned to use `std::vector` could I do that with a double pointer `T **m_` because I'm required to use the pointers.

Comment: @Kevondsmith Yes I thought that it is likely that you are and I am not blaming you for following the instructions you are given. But the point is that it is still bad style and I don't understand why anybody teaches C++ this way. It makes everything more complicated and in most cases is plain wrong because it breaks exception-safety and the like.

Comment: @Kevondsmith Btw. I answered your actual question before the two comments in my answer. You don't have to fix your question. In particular you should never fix the actual problem you are asking about. Now whoever reads the question will not understand my answer anymore. I will revert your last edit.

Comment: Say I was wanting to ask another question that pertained to this same topic, should I ask it in here, or ask another question.

Comment: @Kevondsmith If it isn't directly related to my answer or the same error you were describing in this question, then you should open a new question.

Comment: is it wrong to ask you to go check out my new question I just posted? If so, I'll delete my comment. But its in regards basically to the same type of situation in this post.